# Two-way databinding using Combine

Tags: swift, combine

I'm building a reusable custom stepper view.

[image]

I have it all working, and am using Combine for observing value changes. However, I'd like to improve it by using two-way databinding, but not sure if that is possible?

Here is my current code:

```swift
class Stepper: UIView {
  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setup()
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setup()
  }

  @Published var count = 0

  private let stackView = UIStackView()
  private let minusButton = BorderedRoundButton()
  private let plusButton = BorderedRoundButton()
  private let countLabel = UILabel()
  private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

  func setup() {
    translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    stackView.axis = .horizontal

    minusButton.setTitleColor(.primaryTint, for: .normal)
    plusButton.setTitleColor(.primaryTint, for: .normal)

    minusButton.setTitle("-", for: .normal)
    plusButton.setTitle("+", for: .normal)

    countLabel.text = "0"
    countLabel.textColor = .blackText
    countLabel.font = .preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body)
    countLabel.textAlignment = .center

    stackView.addArrangedSubview(minusButton)
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(countLabel)
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(plusButton)

    minusButton.tapPublisher.sink { [weak self] _ in
      self?.count -= 1
    }.store(in: &cancellables)

    plusButton.tapPublisher.sink { [weak self] _ in
      self?.count += 1
    }.store(in: &cancellables)

    $count.map { "\($0)" }.assign(to: \.text, on: countLabel).store(in: &cancellables)
    $count.map { $0 > 0 }.assign(to: \.isEnabled, on: minusButton).store(in: &cancellables)

    addSubview(stackView)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
      minusButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 38),
      minusButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 38),

      plusButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 38),
      plusButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 38),

      countLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44),

      stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
      stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
      stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
      stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
    ])
  }
}
```

And I am using it like this:

```swift
class PickerViewController: UIViewController {
  @IBOutlet private var stepper: Stepper!
  private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

  @Published var count = 0

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    stepper.count = count

    stepper.$count.sink { [weak self] value in
      self?.count = value
    }.store(in: &cancellables)
  }
}
```

And that is the bit I want to improve: I now need to both set the initial value and then observe the changes. I know it's hardly a lot of code, but I am just wondering if I can do it in one line, with a sort of two-way databinding?

I thought about using SwiftUI's `@Bindable` propertywrapper (or a rebuilt version of it as to not have to import SwiftUI), so that `PickerViewController.count` is the one source, and the Stepper would automatically update it. However, then I have the problem that `@Bindable` is not observable itself, so these lines would no longer work:

```swift
$count.map { "\($0)" }.assign(to: \.text, on: countLabel).store(in: &cancellables)
$count.map { $0 > 0 }.assign(to: \.isEnabled, on: minusButton).store(in: &cancellables)
```

So my question is: can I improve the code to use two-way databinding, or should I just stick with setting the value and then observing it separately?

Comment: I am not sure I understand, but a bindable can be created by providing getter and setter closures. Refer to the Binding initialisers documentation

Comment: Basically I want something like SwiftUI’s @Binding property wrapper so you can you have true two-way databinding, but have it be observable too.

Comment: `SwiftUI`'s `View` is built using a `struct`. SwiftUI is build in such a way that when one of it's dependancies changes the `View` gets  invalidated, so the `body` would be recomputed. That way `SwiftUI` is able to observe changes and be up to date with any data changes. Now you are using UIKit and `class`, so you got to do all the work yourself.

Comment: Hi @KevinRenskers. Did you end up with some solution for this? I'm having similar issue, I want to have two way binding in UIKit as well.

Comment: I wrote a blogpost about it a while ago, maybe it helps you: https://www.loopwerk.io/articles/2020/two-way-databinding-uikit/.